# Is it possible to know when a credit card transaction hits the bank account?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing

I'm building a payment dispursement system; There are plenty of API's from different providers to do ACH transactions to transfer money from one bank account to another, and payment gateways to charge a persons card and the money lands in your bank account eventually.

Payment Gateway -> Merchant Account -> Merchant Designated Bank Account (typically checking)

I need to know when the money hits the bank account, to be able to have code that will automatically transfer a portion of those funds into N number of other accounts via an ACH transaction

I know when the payment gets authorized by the payment gateway (immediate auth/decline) -- what I don't know is when the money will hit the bank account. Does anyone know of specific API's that provide this kind of reporting?

Thanks!

Comment: Just becouse the money is in the bank account does not mean it has cleared, each bank has it's own rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to know this.